# phonegap 2.0 at ios has an error

Tags: ios, cordova

My code works well at android platform(phonegap 2.0 and before).But when i try to run it at ios, it has some problems. 
 If i add cordova2.0.js like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
```

But my app will alert a lot. like these:

["Info","NetworkStatus0",true]

["tDeviceInfo","Device1",true]

When i romove cordova-2.0.0.js tag. The index.html load normally without any alert.
 I don't know why.

Comment: You are probably using deprecated functions. When doing so, cordova gives these errors

Comment: Are you using the same cordova-2.0.0.js from android in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar problem that got fixed by always using the cordova-2.0.0 that xCode creates automatically for you when starting a phonegap-project.

Are you using the android version of the javascript?

Comment: Yes,I don't know that two files are different.I have fixed it now.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cordova library for ios. It seems that you are using the android one, or the path is wrong.